# Using colon in display of numerical time DURATION

Tags: meaning, time, symbols

What was Jeff's time?

> ```
> +--------+----------------------+
> | Person | Time taken (minutes) |
> +--------+----------------------+
> | Jeff   | 0:06                 |
> | John   | 0:07                 |
> | Peter  | 0:05                 |
> +--------+----------------------+
> ```

I have a few questions (beyond deciphering its meaning):

- is this ambiguous?
- is it correct and/or established to use the colon in time **durations** in general?

I would expect to see time durations like "5 minutes and 30 seconds" or "5.5 minutes" or "320 seconds" (and understand them all to mean the same thing).

I think if I were to receive a written message "see you in 5:40" I would interpret that as "see you in 5 hours and 40 minutes", but I am not sure if this is well-defined in English.

Comment: Yes, it's ambiguous, though context might resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: And it's still ambiguous.  It's perfectly reasonable to read Jeff's time as either 6 minutes or 6 seconds from that table, though 0.06 (decimal) minutes (ie about 3.6s) is probably ruled out by the `:`.  Much better, in the table header, to write something like `hh:mm` or `mm:ss`, as appropriate.